# Is there any way to remove middle row from xml using script mediator in wso2 6.5.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I want to retrieve the data from excel. Its almost done but am facing one thing, while retrieving the data from multiple sheets, second and third sheets column name also coming along with value. how to remove that column name alone from the multiple records of data? Please help me to sort out the issues.

```
    <![CDATA[
                    var resultXML = new XML(<sample></sample>)  
                    var csv = mc.getPayloadXML();
                    var count = 0;                              
                    var lines = (csv + "").split("\n");
                    for (var l = 1; l <= lines.length; l++) {
                        var empXML= new XML(<employee></employee>);
                    var cells = (lines[l] + "").split(";");     
                        for each(var value in cells){
                            count++;                                                
                                if(count==1){                                               
                                    empXML.appendChild(<fn>{value}</fn>);
                                }else if(count==2){
                                    empXML.appendChild(<sn>{value}</sn>);
                                }else if(count==3){
                                    empXML.appendChild(<eid>{value}</eid>);
                                count=0;
                                }
                            }
                            resultXML.appendChild(empXML);
                    }
                    var length = resultXML.employee.length();                       
                    delete resultXML.employee[length-1];                
                    mc.setPayloadXML(resultXML);                                    
                    ]]>

Output like :

    <employee>
        <fn>Jhanvi</fn>
        <sn>Raman</sn>
        <eid>180718.0</eid>
      </employee>
      <employee>
        <fn>Sumathi</fn>
        <sn>Marimuthu</sn>
        <eid>240391.0</eid>
      </employee>
      <employee>
        <fn>Sumathi</fn>
        <sn>Muthuraman</sn>
        <eid>250514.0</eid>
      </employee>
      <employee>
        <fn>FirstName</fn>
        <sn>LastName</sn>
        <eid>EmpId</eid>
      </employee>
      <employee>
        <fn>Harshitha</fn>
        <sn>Raman</sn>
        <eid>150715.0</eid>
      </employee>
      <employee>
        <fn>Jhanvi</fn>
        <sn>Raman</sn>
        <eid>180718.0</eid>
      </employee>
      <employee>
        <fn>xxx</fn>
        <sn>yyy</sn>
        <eid>123.0</eid>
      </employee>
      <employee>
        <fn>aaa</fn>
        <sn>bbb</sn>
        <eid>456.0</eid>
      </employee>
```

Comment: Middle record like FirstName,LastName,EmpId is a column name of sheet2. Its also coming along with record.How to remove it? Please guide me to do

Comment: While adding the XML elements, you can have a if check. That is, add the element if the value is not FirstName, LastName & EmpId.

Comment: First of all Thanks. But that condition check not work and not possible at all suppose column name dynamic means how we can check? Now i hard coded the column name for checking purpose.Then, i handled this condition with custom class its working finely. Thanks once again.